# How to resume a method from its last return point?

Tags: android, c#, iterator, yield-return

I wish to know if there is some kind of mechanism in C# which allows to "resume" a method from the last return that it reached during the its last invocation.

**WHAT I NEED:** I have an Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) which is created by a Parser designed from a source language. This Abstract Syntax Tree is an object of a "root class" which have as fields instances of other classes and so on. What I need to do is to create a **sequencer** which takes this Abstract Syntax Tree and through a **generator** creates instructions in other language. The instructions sequence terminates with a null. This is possible through a generator method **`next()`**, which invokes a sequencer method which computes on-the-fly the next instruction. In other words, I can't explore the whole Abstract Syntax Tree, generates all the instructions and return them one-by-one every time that I call `next()`, but I MUST create each one of them every time that the generator call next().

**AN EXAMPLE**: I will post a pseudo code in order to make you better understand the problem.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{Parser parser = new Parser (//constructor stuff);
 Sequencer sequencer = new Sequencer(parser.Parse()); //the mehtod Parse() generates the AST
 Generator generator = new Generator(sequencer);
 Instruction instruction = generator.next();
 while(instruction)
      {print instruction
       instruction = generator.next();
      } 
}
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** the most important thing that I wish that you understand is that `next()` is not always called inside a some kind of iteration, **so I don't think that `foreach` and iterators are a good solution.**

This because in order to use iterotors I have finally to write something like

```
foreach(instruction in next())
       {//do stuff with instruction}
```

And I don't want to do that!

However, I will make you see how `next()` should be structured:

```
Instruction next()
{ return sequencer.generate();}
```

And so `generate()`:

```
Instruction generate():
{Insturction instr;
while(I explored the whole AST)
      {if(//actual node in the AST is this kind)
          instr=//generate this instruction
      else if(//actual node in the AST is this other kind)
          instr=//generate this other instruction
      else and so on....
      //if the actual node has some child, then it is new actual node
      **yield return** instruction;
      }
 }
```

The most complicate part is that I need something with a `yield return` behaviour (so starting where I left at the next `generate()` calling, but without using iterator for the reasons that I explained before. In addiction to that, it is extremely difficult to move inside the AST since I cannot have an explicit reference of the parent of the actual node (like a field which is a copy of the actual node).

As it is not sufficient, you can recursively call `generate` (for example if there is some kind of iterative constructor to translate).

How to achieve this?

Comment: It would be easy to answer if you tell what problem you're trying to solve. This looks like a [XYProblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). btw what you're asking is called state machine.

Comment: Is the only problem that you want to `yield return (nothing);` instead of `yield return some_object;` ?

Comment: I'm agree with you, but I cannot post the entire "code generator" program in this post...in addiction to that I should post the Abstract Syntax Tree classes and maybe the Parser code too. Obviously, this is not possible :D

Comment: I edited the whole question in order to make understand better the problem and its constraints. I hope that it will helps you (and me :P )

Comment: @LovaJ. - I guess misunderstanding comes from the fact that you insist that `IEnumerator.Current`/`IEnumerator.MoveNext()` pair is absolutely inferior to single "next()" method... If you really just need `next()` why not to wrap C#-created iterator with helper class with single method? Not sure why you consider `foreach` and `IEnumerable` as single non-separable concept...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, [`yield`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx), along with the [`IEnumerator<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) do satisfy your requirements. The key point to note is that [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) exposes the [`GetEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s793z9y2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, which is exactly what you need here.

Generator:

```
public class Generator
{
    //...

    public IEnumerable<Instruction> Generate()
    {
        // ...
        yield return new Instruction(...);
        // ...
    }
    //...
}
```

An example on how to use it the way you want. The key part is that you can do `generator.Generate().GetEnumerator();`:

```
var enumerator = generator.Generate().GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    var instruction = enumerator.Current;
    // do something with instruction

    if (steps > 10)  //some dummy reason to stop ordinary iteration
        break;
}

// Now process generator's results manually

if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
    throw new InstructionMissingException();   // no more instructions left

var followingInstruction = enumerator.Current;

// ...

if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
    throw new InstructionMissingException();   // no more instructions left

var theLastInstruction = enumerator.Current;

// ...

if (enumerator.MoveNext())
    throw new TooMuchInstructionsException(); // unexpected instruction
```

I've noticed that `GetEnumerator` can be called on `IEnumerable` thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9254448/2642204) which answers a similar question.

Additionally, as [Alexei Levenkov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477420/alexei-levenkov) points out in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25586272/c-sharp-start-a-method-from-last-return/25590289#comment39968879_25586272) you can wrap `MoveNext` and `Current` with a comfortable method that suits your needs more accurately. You could even write an extension method for the `IEnumerator<Instruction>` type:

```
public static class IEnumeratorExtensions
{
    public static Instruction NextInstruction(this IEnumerator<Instruction> @this)
    {
        if (@this.MoveNext())
        {
            return @this.Current;
        }

        return null; // or throw, or whatever you like
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's the best until now! However, I have still somehting to ask you: supposing that the only thing to do in the generator method `next()` is:

     `var enumerator = generator.Generate().GetEnumerator();`
     `return enumerator.Current;`

I ask you: the next time that I invoke next, and so `GetEnumerator()`, the `Generate()` method will start from where I left (so `yield return` line) or from the beginning again?

Comment: @LovaJ. That's how `yield` works: after each time you call `MoveNext` the execution of the method will "wait" on this `yield` statement. After you call `MoveNext` it will continue from this point - either to the next `yield` (or the same if in a loop), or to the end of the method, in case of which `MoveNext` will return `false`. Refer to the examples in the links I've given in my answer (the `yield` link in particular).

Comment: Thanks for your help, through your answers I was able to implement an iterator solution which solved my problem! Thanks to you, now I know `GetEnumerator()` and I know the iterators features better , thanks again! :D

Answer (score 3):

Use `yield return` to implement the main logic.  That'll create an enumerator.  Store it in a class member variable or somewhere else permanent.

Then use that enumerator inside a wrapper method that returns the plain object, pulling one new item from the enumerator on each call.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not a good solution for my problem, because this would mean that I have to explore the entire Abstract Syntax Tree generated by the Parser...and I don't want to do that: I want to explore it until I reach the next possible instruction to generate and stop there. At the next method call which explore the AST, I want to start from where I left the last time.

Comment: @lovaJ: If that's what you want to do, then do that.  When you generate one, `yield return` it.  If you don't need a return value, just return a dummy `int` or something.

Comment: +1. @LovaJ. It is very unclear why "this would mean that I have to explore the entire Abstract Syntax Tree". There no requirements to finish enumeration... You can easily have infinite enumerator (and you definitely don't need to enumerate all items like `int` to return next one).