# Open XML - read certain excel cells

Tags: c#, openxml

I need to loop .xlsx rows, using OpenXML. When cell value matches my string I need to read value from cell in next column, same row. Here is what I have so far:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    using (SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fs, false))
    {
        WorkbookPart workbookPart = doc.WorkbookPart;
        SharedStringTablePart sstpart = workbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().First();
        SharedStringTable sst = sstpart.SharedStringTable;
        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
        Worksheet sheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;
        var rows = sheet.Descendants<Row>();

        foreach (Row row in rows)
        {
            foreach (Cell c in row.Elements<Cell>())
            {
                if ((c.DataType != null) && (c.DataType == CellValues.SharedString))
                {
                    int ssid = int.Parse(c.CellValue.Text);
                    string str = sst.ChildElements[ssid].InnerText;

                    if (str == "Date of birth:")
                    {
                        Cell next_cell = row.Descendants<Cell>().ElementAt(ssid + 1);
                        MessageBox.Show(next_cell.CellValue.Text);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't show me value from correct cell, so please someone point me to correct way of doing this in OpenXML.

EDIT: It would be nice to know how to define a cell outside loop too.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've found the correct `Row` you are using the index into the Shared Strings Table (`ssid`) rather than the index of the `Row`.

There are various ways to fix it but essentially you need to go to the next `Row` for the value rather than the `Row` that happens to match the next shared string index.

The approach that's closest to your current code would be to keep an index of the cell on when looping and use that to index the `Row`:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    using (SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fs, false))
    {
        WorkbookPart workbookPart = doc.WorkbookPart;
        SharedStringTablePart sstpart = workbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().First();
        SharedStringTable sst = sstpart.SharedStringTable;
        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
        Worksheet sheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;
        var rows = sheet.Descendants<Row>();

        foreach (Row row in rows)
        {
            int cellIndex = 0;

            foreach (Cell c in row.Elements<Cell>())
            {
                if ((c.DataType != null) && (c.DataType == CellValues.SharedString))
                {
                    int ssid = int.Parse(c.CellValue.Text);
                    string str = sst.ChildElements[ssid].InnerText;

                    if (str == "Date of birth:")
                    {
                        Cell next_cell = row.Descendants<Cell>().ElementAt(cellIndex + 1);
                        MessageBox.Show(next_cell.CellValue.Text);
                    }
                }

                cellIndex++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on your needs there are other approaches such as changing to a `for` loop or grabbing the enumerator directly as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9254448/3791802).

Comment: thanks for response, this might help to me. Beside that, are you maybe aware of how could I define a cell outside loop ? That would help me even  more. I found this [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722808/using-linq-with-open-xml-excel), but nothing works for me ? ....I've edited question for this.

Comment: @Lucy82 - I'm not sure what you mean by "define a cell outside loop", could you elaborate?

Comment: sure. My problem is that I need to save values of Excel file under certain columns. So first I need to search cells with column headers to get column index, in order to get desired values from For Each. Problem is because when inside For Each statement code reads only SharedString values and ignores number and Datetime types, so it skips line **if ((c.DataType != null) && (c.DataType == CellValues.SharedString))**....And then It's hard to link desired data with column. I hope you understand better now.

Comment: @Lucy82 - it sounds like you need to find the index of each cell you are interested in (similar to `cellIndex` in my code above) on the first row then on subsequent rows you can iterate the cells until you get to the index(es) you are interested in and grab the value from that cell. As long as you increment your counter outside your `if ((c.DataType...` code you should be fine?